# How to use parameter to initialize the size of std::array in a class constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

For example:

```
#Include <array>

class UnionFind final {
 public:
  explicit UnionFind(int numbers) {
    // ???
  }

 private:
  std::array<int, ???> array_;
};
```

I want to initialize `array_` as `std::array<int, numbers>` in the constructor `UnionFind(int numbers)`, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: you probably want `std::vector` then

Comment: You need to know the size of the `std::array` at compile-time. If you don't, `std::vector` is a better option.

Comment: Please don't be sloppy when posting on this site. Your original post failed to format the code properly and was thus obscuring a very important detail of your question. Take the extra minute to proof-read your finished post. It's a tiny sacrifice compared to the many minutes of attention you are getting from people who are willing to help you for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) 's size must be specified at compile time, such as:

```
template <std::size_t numbers>
class UnionFind final {
public:
  UnionFind() {}

private:
  std::array<int, numbers> array_;
};
```

then (suppose the size is fixed as 3)

```
UnionFind<3> u;
```

If you want to specify the size at run time, you may want to use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
class UnionFind final {
public:
  explicit UnionFind(int numbers) : array_(numbers) {}

private:
  std::vector<int> array_;
};
```

Comment: Better use `size_t` as template parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `std::vector` instead of a template class? Access time of an existing `std::array` is the same speed than of a `std::vector` and since the object needs to be allocated during runtime anyway you don't really win any speed performance.